# Native Mobile app for presta shop

Tags: php, android, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

I want to develop a native android application for my PrestaShop store. I have been searching on Google for a while but all i found was third party applications that says they can create an application for mobile. The documentation doesn't provide a clear answer as well.

Does prestashop provide an API for mobile applications ? or is there any open-source native mobile application for presta-shop ?

All I want to know is that where should I start from. May be I am not searching for the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will use api to call WebService, and use the information for develop your native application, you only need consume the information .

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service